# Some Programs cannot access mounted external usb drive

Tags: usb, mount

Files and Terminal can access the mounted external usb drive using current user permission.

However third party program say Jdownloader cannot see the external usb drive.

it is mounted as:

```
UUID=device-uuid /media/user/alpha auto rw,relatime,uhelper=udisks2 0 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be security context enforcement.

Running JDownloader manually from command line (so it runs as securitycontext: unconfined) it can access the usb drives fine (previously it runs as "enforced")

Comment: It's a snap and like most snaps by default it accesses only /home/USER. Most snaps can be given permission to also access mount points under /mnt or /media (but nothing else). It can be done with commands or graphically in Ubuntu Software. This isn't anything new so, sorry, no Nobel Prize for you.